# Endogeneity and omitted variables

Tags: nonlinear, endogeneity

Assume you observe the time series x and construct the time-series a, b and c.

Then, you argue that x causes y = f(a,b,c), where f is known and non-linear. The relation in contemporaneous.

You regress y on x and get high correlation.

How do you support the causality hypothesis?

Does it make sense to regress y on x, a, b, and c?

What does it mean if you get R2 close to one and x is significant?